# Where is the data in $_FILES array?

Tags: php, file

I understand uploading files to the server and the 2D $_FILES array.

You can access

`$_FILES['myFile']['name'], $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']` etc.

What I don't understand is how do I just get the file data that I uploaded? If I wanted to do something like fill a variable with the file data, how do I do that?

`$fileVar = $_FILES['myFile'];`

Will that work? I have tried that and it doesn't seem to work, although it maybe some other problem. Anyway this is a little confusing to me, all I want is the file data.

The `$_FILES['myFile']['name'], $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']` etc is great but where is the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The uploaded file, and therefore its data, it stored in the file with the path in `$_FILES[...]['tmp_name']`. That's the uploaded file. To gets its data, read it like any other file:

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first study documentation about [handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Posted files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory. They will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if they have not been moved or renamed.

If you want to get file content as a string, you can try:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] );
```

Comment: Studied it for many hours and written a lot of test code. finaly coming to the forums for answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

`$fileVar = $_FILES['myFile']; $fileVar` is the array that you need.

`$_FILES['myFile']['tmpname']` is just a string that have the temp path of a uploaded file.